# Object is being spammed when it comes to my timeBetweenShot variable, can anyone take a look?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I Have created a 2d stealth game where the enemy fires on the player, only problem is that although the bullets are created and deleted fine on another script, the script itself spams the program with bullets every frame, creating the unwanted result

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HurtPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{

public float timeToShoot;
private float timeToShootCounter;
private bool shot;
private Vector3 moveDirection;
public float timeBetweenShot;
public float timeBetweenShotCounter;

public Transform firePoint;
public GameObject Bullet;



// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    shot = false;
    timeToShootCounter = timeToShoot;


}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    while (shot == true)
    {
        StartCoroutine(Delay());
        Destroy(GameObject.Find("Bullet"));
        timeBetweenShot -= Time.deltaTime;
        timeToShoot -= Time.deltaTime;
    }


}

IEnumerator Delay()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
}

void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "player")
    {
        if (shot == false)
        {

            if (timeToShoot >= 0f)
            {
                shot = true;
                if (shot == true)
                {
                    shot = false;
                    Instantiate(Bullet, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);

                    Delay();
                    if (timeBetweenShot <= 0f)
                    {
                        shot = false;
                        timeToShoot = timeToShootCounter;
                        timeBetweenShot = timeBetweenShotCounter;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

What I want is the time betweenshot to work and for the enemy to only shoot once every one or half a second, thanks.

Comment: The title is for you to briefly explain your problem, not to say "my code doesn't work"

Comment: This logic is too complex for such a task i think. Why don't you get a flag in `OnTriggerStay2D` and while the flag is true instantiate a bullet in every 0.5 sec?

Comment: Also the while loop in Update is completely useless. The only reason why you haven't completely frozen the editor yet is that `shot` is never true except for an instant in the `OnTriggerStay` where it is immediately set to false again.

Comment: Your `Delay` doesn't do anything. It doesn't delay the code that comes afterwards, even if you called it correctly using StartCoroutine. Calling it directly doesn't run the code as a Coroutine, but even if it did you can only delay code _inside_ the Coroutine.

Comment: Lastly, instead of `if(shot == true)` you can simply write `if(shot)`

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
IEnumerator ContinuousShoot()
{
    // Continuously spawn bullets until this coroutine is stopped
    // when the player exits the trigger.
    while (true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f); // Pause for 1 second.
        Instantiate(Bullet, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
    }
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    // Player enters trigger
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("player"))
    {
        StartCoroutine(ContinuousShoot());
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
{
    // Player exits trigger
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("player"))
    {
        StopCoroutine(ContinuousShoot());
    }
}
```